# Core dump error while returning from a function

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
void function(const string param1, string *p2param, string *retparam)
```

when this is invoked from `main`, execution goes till last line of this function and then fails with

```
Bus Error(coredump)
```

The function performs some string manipulation using pointer to string and then the final value is passed to `*retparam`.

The code goes like this aa.c has

```
string *f1;//global
string f2= "abc";//global

function_2()
{
stringstream aa;
*f1 += aa<<"test";
//similar concatenation
 }
function(param1, *p2param, *retparam)
{
  /* assign back the values*/
  f1 =&f2;
  //call to a function from bb.c
  // from bb.c function_2() is in called
   retparam = f1
 }
```

The only information I could get is:

```
pstack core
$ pstack core
core 'core' of 4517:    aa_test -t 745
 ffffffff7c67109c __1cDstdMbasic_string4Ccn0ALchar_traits4Cc__n0AJallocator4Cc___2T5B6M_v_ (ffffffff7fffce98, 1002805fc, 10010cc90, 0, ffffffff7c8c3bd8, ffffffff7fffce98) + 14
 0000000100004498 main (10010b000, 100000, ffffffff7fffce98, ffffffff7fffcf00, ffffffff7fffd288, ffffffff7fffd0b8) + 818
 0000000100003a7c _start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 17c
```

What is causing this error?

Thanks for your valueable inputs which finally has sorted out my issue.

The issue was with the typecast of string variable
code snippet

```
void function(const string param1, string *p2param, string *retparam)  {  
   //function to call from bb.c has prototype
    //fun2(const char **str,stubfunc)
    const char *l_str = param1.c_str();
    fun2((const char **) &l_str,coverage_hook);
}
//this was ealier called as 
//fun2((const char**) &param1,coverage_hook); hence was causing the core dump 
//why?? still dont know :)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and its not obvious how to make it work. Its much more helpful if you provide a complete example exhibiting the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

If `retparam` is the address of an actual `string` when you pass it in, then what you really want to do before returning is

```
(*retparam) = f2;
```

Setting the value of `retparam` itself isn't doing you any good, since it's a local variable in the function, and changing its value won't change anything in the parent. But you can change the memory it *points* to, which is what happens here.

Comment: But `retparam` is a local variable. (It's a pointer, but the pointer itself is passed by value.) How could anything be attempting to use it after the function returns?

Comment: See my edited answer for (probably) the right solution. It relies on `retparam` being a real address of a real `string` object.

Comment: I think your updated version is accurate, but I don't see how it addresses whatever's causing the core-dump. (I'm not saying it doesn't; I just don't see how it does. I think it would help if you explained what *is* causing the core-dump.)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to f2 which is a local variable that gets destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a bit of a stab in the dark here, but I think your problem *might* be that you're defining the function like this:

```
void function(const string param1, string *p2param, string *retparam)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

but you're forward-declaring it somewhere (in a header file?) like this:

```
string function(const string param1, string *p2param, string *retparam);
```

(promising that it will have return-type `string` rather than `void`). So when the function returns, the calling code tries to use its return-value, and pandemonium ensues when it turns out there *isn't* one.

(If that's not the case — and it may well not be — then I think it would help if you posted the full function definition, as well as the code that invokes the function.)